# Unable to connect two LG screens, GeForce GTX 750

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have trouble to connect two screens in my computer. I installed (with one screen) Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 (just to try) and everything is ok. But then I try to connect the other screen and everything turns black. Everything crash. I tried to install the drivers of my graphic card but it doesn't works. It's even worse, because after that my computer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Ubuntu with whatever version, open the System settings and go to Software and updates[image]

Then go to additional drivers tab and select a (proprietary, tested) driver and hit apply changes :
[image]